# Dynamically loaded images are not visible in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am using `Gallery` and I am loading a set of images from server through URL of those Images. I am converting them to `Bitmap` and I am adding those to a `Bitmap` array. Then I am using an Adapter class which extends `BaseAdapter` and I am setting the images in the `ImageSwitcher` inside `getView()`. Coming to the output 
I am getting the images fine in the `Gallery` strip, But I don't see any Images in the `ImageSwitcher`.

Even when I click the images one by one from that strip I am not getting any images in the `ImageSwitcher`.

When I load the images statically everything works fine, But when I do it dynamically I am getting a blank `ImageSwitcher`

I used the code from [here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/05/12/imageswitcher-android/)

[Here is a screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mwfm.png)

[image]

Any Solutions???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using `ImageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(your drawable)` where instead I was using `ImageSwitcher.setBackground(your drawable)` which caused the problem for me.